# in java Servlets are used to create dynamically generated content

Tags: java

in java servlets are used to create dynamically generated content,here what is dynamically mean? and what is the content?

is dynamically refers that the web page is constantly changes with the content that extracted form database like present dollar in rupees conversion which constantly changes which is dynamically mean  is it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HttpServlets contents refer to responds to http request, the most obvious its an html page, but you can generate whatever like .css, .js, json responses, binary responses...

Dynamic refers to the ability to generate this resources "on the fly" composing the content with the result of some calculation or with some other external content as databases or other web services for example.

Answer (score 0):

It means that instead of serving static html pages i.e. pages that are plain files in your disk and served to clients per request and the clients all view the same page, with servlets you can build pages at run time making customization and passing parameters as needed so clients see a different page